# "Heap use after free" error in LeetCode Online Judge but not Visual Studio

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-c++, heap-memory

I am coding a solution to the LeetCode problem "Odd Even Linked List" which can be read [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/odd-even-linked-list/).

My code is failing the test case with the error

```
================================================================
==31==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x6020000000d8 at pc 0x0000003d7f1d bp 0x7fff37cf9640 sp 0x7fff37cf9638
READ of size 8 at 0x6020000000d8 thread T0
```

However, when I run the code in Visual Studio to diagnose the error, everything works. The solution for LeetCode is here:

```
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* oddEvenList(ListNode* head) {
        
        if (!head){
            return head;
        }
        
        ListNode* odd_head = head;
        ListNode* even_head = odd_head->next;
        
        if (!even_head){
            return head;
        }
        
        ListNode* last_odd = odd_head;
        ListNode* last_even = even_head;
        ListNode* next_node = even_head->next;
        
        bool flag = true;
        
        while(true){
            if (!next_node){
                break;
            }
            if (flag){
                last_odd -> next = next_node;
                last_odd = next_node;
            } else {
                last_even -> next = next_node;
                last_even = next_node;
            }
            
            flag = !flag;
            
            next_node = (next_node->next);
            
        }
        last_odd->next = even_head;
        
        return odd_head;
    }
};
```

The code I am using to test the above is here:

```
#include "oddevenlinkedlist.h"

#include <iostream>
int main() {

    ListNode* l1 = new ListNode(1);
    ListNode* l2 = new ListNode(2);
    l1->next = l2;
    ListNode* l3 = new ListNode(3);
    l2->next = l3;
    ListNode* l4 = new ListNode(4);
    l3->next = l4;
    ListNode* l5 = new ListNode(5);
    l4->next = l5;

    Solution solution{};
    ListNode* result = solution.oddEvenList(l1);
    ListNode* next_node = result;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        std::cout << next_node->val << " ";
        next_node = next_node->next;
    }

    delete l1;
    delete l2;
    delete l3;
    delete l4;
    delete l5;

    return 0;
}
```

If you wish to test this, you will want the definition of a `ListNode` which is here:

```
struct ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode* next;
    ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
    ListNode(int x, ListNode* next) : val(x), next(next) {}
    
};
```

Because the code works on my compiler, I am having trouble diagnosing the error. While of course I hope someone can identify the error, my question is this: **why is MSVS not catching the "heap-use-after-free" error?**

Comment: There is no `delete` or `free` in the code you posted. Are you sure that's the real, whole code?

Comment: @dxiv ah, yes, I missed ```delete``` in ```main```. I almost always use smart pointers in my own code, so I forgot here. Adding delete does not change the behavior; MSVS still outputs the expected result.

Comment: You are wasting both yours and everyone else's time if you don't post the *exact* code that exhibits the problem you are asking for help with.

Comment: @dxiv this is the exact code. If you past the first ```Solution``` class into LeetCode, it will give the error I posted. The full code I have given is exactly what I put is MSVS. Don't forget that ```ListNode``` is defined at the bottom.

Comment: @mana I take it that your don't post the `main` function to LeetCode, just the solution class? In other words the LeetCode 'engine' is doing some allocation and deletion that is different from your main funciton?

Comment: @mana If that is the case then I would guess that you messed up the linked list somehow, so that the same node appears twice in your linked list. That would explain why LeetCode deletes the same node twice, but how in your code where you just delete the same five variables you allocated you don;t see the problem.

Comment: @john yes. In LeetCode, you only define the ```Solution``` class. The second display with the ```main``` function was written by me. It is my guess of what LeetCode would do to test my code.

Comment: @mana Put another way all the stuff I posted about undefined behaviour is besides the point, you're running two different programs and seeing two different results. No explanation is needed

Comment: @john if you run my test code in MSVS, the output is ```1 3 5 2 4```. That says to me that the same node isn't appearing twice in the linked list. This is the exact test case that gives an error in LeetCode.

Comment: @mana On that small example yes, but there's absoutely no guarantee that your code works in every example.

Comment: @mana See this problem all the time, code fails on an online judge, but the judge doesn't say what the input data that caused the failure is. So the programmer is left scratching their head.

Comment: @john I just found the error in the code. You were correct. I didn't set ```next``` of the last node to ```nullptr```, so LeetCode was accessing a node it may have already deleted. I wasn't deleting nodes as I read them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most things that you can do wrong in a C++ program fall into the category of [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). Using memory after is has been freed, dereferencing a null pointer, reading an uninitialised variable, reading or writing beyond the bounds of an array, all of these invoke undefined behaviour.

Undefined behaviour means that the C++ standard does not require any particular behaviour from an affected program. Producing an error message, throwing an exception, working apparently normally and crashing are all permitted behaviours (as is anything else). So it's not wrong that MSVS did not produce any kind of error.

Beginners especially sometimes have a hard time with undefined behaviour, but when they do its a philosophical problem, the concept itself is quite simple.

The reason that C++ has the concept of undefined behaviour is also simple. Checking for errors takes time. Code that detects errors will run slower than code that doesn't even if the errors don't occur. Undefined behaviour permits compiler writers not to check for errors and therefore to produce faster code.

Now checking for errors is obviously useful, especially for debugging. So most compilers have various options whereby some errors are detected. It makes sense that a compiler running as an online judge would have the error detection turned up as high as possible.

Comment: That's all true, of course, but it's not obvious where the UB is in OP's posted code.

Comment: @dxiv I agree, but the question was specifically about why one compiler gives an error and the other doesn't.

Comment: @dxiv Added a bit more about why the difference might be there.

Comment: No argument there, but assuming for the sake of discussion that OP's is the *real, whole code* (which btw I don't think it is), the answer could be either that one compiler is wrong, or that the other one is not required to. The distinguishing difference between the two cases is whether the code invokes UB or not.

Comment: @dxiv Granted, I am assuming that the 'use after free' message is genuine.

Comment: The difference here isn't that he has UB, which may or may not generate an error message. The difference is that his code frees the linked list nodes in a way that works even though the linked list isn't properly terminated, but the online judge apparently walks through the linked list to delete the nodes, so the improper termination generates an error message. If the online judge used his `main` as shown above, it wouldn't generate an error message either.

Answer (score 16):

#### Underlying Problem

At least from the looks of things, the problem is that you're failing to terminate your linked list correctly.

You're starting with a single linked list, and separating it into odd and even pieces just fine.

Then at the end, you (correctly) concatenate the `evens` list to the end of the `odds` list.

But then you missed one point: the last node in the `evens` list (at least potentially) has a non-null `next` pointer. Specifically, if the last element of the list was an odd element, that last even element will still have a pointer to the last odd element.

So for a 5 element list you'll get something like this:

[image]

Obviously, when you put the two pieces together, after the `last_odd->next = even_head;`, you need to add something like `last_even->next = nullptr;` so the concatenated list will be terminated.

#### The Difference

In the code you've shown above, you start by allocating five nodes, and then finish by deleting exactly the same five nodes, ignoring the structure of the linked list.

But the online judge apparently walks through the linked list, and deletes nodes as it gets to them in the linked list. So, when it walks through the linked list you returned, after it gets to the last node, it follows the non-null next pointer to the last `odd` node, and tries to delete it--but since it's already been deleted, an error is generated.

Comment: This solved my issue with this leetcode problem. Thanks!

Comment: > At least from the looks of things, the problem is that you're failing to terminate your linked list correctly.
The statement is correct in identifying the issue as a failure to terminate the linked list correctly. In the specific case mentioned, the problem was encountered while solving problem 23 (Merge k Sorted Lists). After swapping nodes, setting tail->next to nullptr resolved the issue. Therefore, the solution provided by the previous answer was effective in solving the problem. Thank you for the help.